# Array Search over Array of objects - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array

```
var arr = ['0333', '0444', '0334'];
```

And i have an array of objects.

```
var objArray = [{'name':'abc', 'phone':'0333'}, 
                {'name':'xyz', 'phone':'0334'},
                {'name':'fgfh', 'phone':'0999'},
                {'name':'abc', 'phone':'0666'},
                {'name':'abc', 'phone':'0444'} 
               ]
```

Now i want to make a search for all `arr` values/indexes in `objArray` and separate objects with **matching values**, and separate with **no matching values**

```
var matchingArray = [];
var noMatchingArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < objArray.length; j++) {
            if(objArray[j]['phone'] == arr[i]){
                matchingArray.push(objArray);
             }
        }
}
```

How do i add no matching objects to `noMatchingArray` ?

Comment: What's the expected result for `matchingArray` and `noMatchingArray`?

Comment: `else { noMatchingArray.push(objArray[j]); }`, as well as `matchingArray.push(objArray[j]);` in preceding line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should works fine

```
objArray.forEach(item => arr.indexOf(item.phone) >=0 ? matchingArray.push(item) : noMatchingArray.push(item))
```

Comment: Why are you using map? bad choice

Comment: @epascarello Yeah, you're right. Changed to `forEach`

Comment: `Array.prototype.includes` won't work in IE. Might be better to just stick with `indexOf`.

Comment: Thanks @AlexK for your suggestion. changed from `Array.prototype.includes` to `indexOf`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Array.prototype.map() [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with normal function or [arrow](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0ahUKEwjqw8rQn-vWAhXB6Y8KHWnJCj8QFgg2MAM&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FFunctions%2FArrow_functions&usg=AOvVaw3deWFLtaJrVNU89etTaa3v) function.

The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

**Noraml Map** without ES6

```js
var arr = ['0333', '0444', '0334'],
    objArray = [{
            'name': 'abc',
            'phone': '0333'
        },{
            'name': 'xyz',
            'phone': '0334'
        },{
            'name': 'fgfh',
            'phone': '0999'
        },{
            'name': 'abc',
            'phone': '0666'
        },{
            'name': 'abc',
            'phone': '0444'
        }
    ];
var rec='',res = arr.map(function(val){
    rec = objArray.find(function(obj){return obj.phone == val});
    if (rec) {
        return rec;
    }
});
console.log(res);
```

**In ES6**

```js
const arr = ['0333', '0444', '0334'],
    objArray = [{
            'name': 'abc',
            'phone': '0333'
        },{
            'name': 'xyz',
            'phone': '0334'
        },{
            'name': 'fgfh',
            'phone': '0999'
        },{
            'name': 'abc',
            'phone': '0666'
        },{
            'name': 'abc',
            'phone': '0444'
        }
    ];
let res = arr.map(val => {
    let rec = objArray.find(obj => obj.phone == val);
    if (rec) {
        return rec;
    }
});
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all, modify your existing loops and add a break statement. If I do not misunderstand the purpose of your match algorithm, you want to stop looking for a match for this phone number, if you have already matched.

Moreover, I think you have an error in your code. You do not want to push the objArray in the matchingArray, right? Just the matchedObject -> j

Answering your question. I would work with a second loop looking over all objects in the objArray, pushing those who are not in the array matchingArray to the noMatchingArray.

```
var matchingArray = [];
    var noMatchingArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < objArray.length; j++) {
                if(objArray[j]['phone'] == arr[i]){
                    matchingArray.push(objArray[j]);
                    break;
                 }
            }
    }

   for (var j = 0; j < objArray.length; j++) {
       var marked = false;
       for (var i = 0; i < matchingArray.length; i++) {
           if (objArray[j] === matchingArray[i]) {
               marked = true;
               break;
           }
       }
       if(!marked){
           noMatchingArray.push(objArray[j]);
       }
   }
```

even better: combining both loops back together while switching inner and outer look of your initial algorithm makes it even more readable and faster than my first solution.

```
var matchingArray = [];
var noMatchingArray = [];
for (var j = 0; j < objArray.length; j++) {
    var marked = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if(objArray[j]['phone'] == arr[i]){
                matchingArray.push(objArray[j]);
                marked = true;
                break;
             }
    }
    if(!marked){
       noMatchingArray.push(objArray[j]);
   }
}
```

Comment: See accepted answer. One liner approach vs tons of lines.

Answer (score -1):

```
function SearchArray() {
    var arr = ['0333', '0444', '0334'];
    var objArray = [{ 'name': 'abc', 'phone': '0333' },
    { 'name': 'fgfh', 'phone': '0999' },
    { 'name': 'abc', 'phone': '0666' },
    { 'name': 'abc', 'phone': '0444' }
    ];

    var matchingArray = [];
    var noMatchingArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var isFound = false;
        for (var j = 0; j < objArray.length; j++) {
            if (objArray[j]['phone'] == arr[i]) {
                matchingArray.push(objArray[j]);
                isFound = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!isFound)
        {
            noMatchingArray.push(arr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```